# Replacing "[aA09.b]." to "[aA09.b]\n" in in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this string:

```
var inputString = "Some text [ some text here . some more text] . some sentence."
```

The `.` should be replaced by `\n` provided it isn't in between `[ ]`.

Expected result:

```
"Some text [ some text here . some more text] \n some sentence\n"
```

I think a quick regular expression could help, but I'm not sure where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Can the string contain multiple [] or even  nested [] ?

Comment: Edited the question. I didn't think it was that bad - it was clear and had expected result. Of course it could have been nicer/less demanding, and the formatting was a mess, but we've all see far worse `:)`

Comment: Seems to be a very reasonable question with a very clear, concise and descriptive title as well. An advanced iterative recursive callback regex solution (which correctly handles the cases [having [nested] brackets]) would have been quite educational for those wishing to advance their JavaScript regex skills. The folks downvoting and closing this question (-1) are the ones who really need the help here. Too bad! :(

Comment: I see that this question has been re-opened (+1). For those interested in seeing how one can effectively handle matching nested structures using JavaScript regex, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming brackets do not contain more brackets, you can use [`replace` with a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
var s = inputString.replace(/(\[[^\]]*\])|(\.)/g,
                        function(g0,brackets,dot){ return brackets || '\n';}
                        );
```

The regex captures the brackets `(\[[^\]]*\])` so it can be used for replacing when it was captures, and used `\n` when `\.` was captured.
Essentially, this is "skipping" over dots inside brackets.

Comment: Please don't spoonfeed users like this. The OP should've made an attempt instead of just asking for copypasta-able code

Comment: @Bojangles while there is a point in what you say there are much nicer ways to ask users to show their efforts. Your comment on the question is rude, plain and simple.

Comment: I'm going to take a Linus Torvalds stance on my rudeness here: quite frankly, I don't care

Answer (score 1):

Kobi's single regex replace solution is short, simple, fast, accurate and elegant. It correctly handles strings with non-nested bracketed structures.

### JavaScript Solution [for [Nested] Brackets]

To correctly handle nested brackets using JavaScript, a more complex iterative solution is required. Since JavaScript regex syntax does not provide recursive expressions, it is impossible to match the outermost pair of matching brackets when the brackets are nested. However, it is quite easy to write a regex which correctly matches an *innermost* pair of matching brackets:

### `/\[([^[\]]*)\]/g`

The tested JavaScript function below handles nested structures by iteratively matching the innermost brackets from the inside out, "hiding" the bracket and dot characters as it goes. (The square bracket and dot characters are temporarily replaced with their equivalent HTML entities.) Once all the dots within the (possibly nested) bracketed text have been "hidden", all the remaining dots in the string, (which fall outside the brackets), are replaced with line feeds. Once this is complete, all the temporarily hidden characters are restored. Since HTML entities are being used internally by this function as temporary placeholders, any pre-existing HTML entities that were in the original string are preserved at the start and then restored at the end.

```js
function replaceDotsNotInBrackets(text) {
    // Regex to match innermost brackets capturing contents in $1.
    var re_inner_brackets = /\[([^[\]]*)\]/g;
    // Firstly, hide/protect any/all existing html entities.
    text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    // Iteratively "Hide" dots within brackets from inside out.
    // Hide dots and brackets by converting to decimal entities:
    // Change [ to &#91;
    // Change ] to &#93;
    // Change . to &#46;
    while (text.search(re_inner_brackets) !== -1) {
        text = text.replace(re_inner_brackets,
            function(m0, m1){
                return "&#91;"+ m1.replace(/\./g, "&#46;") +"&#93;";
            });
    } // All matching brackets and contained dots are now "hidden".
    // Replace all dots outside of brackets with a linefeed.
    text = text.replace(/\./g, "\n");
    // Unhide all previously hidden brackets and dots.
    text = text.replace(/&#(?:91|46|93);/g,
        function(m0){
            return {"&#91;": "[", "&#46;": ".", "&#93;": "]"}[m0];
        });
    // Lastly, restore previously existing html entities.
    return text.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
}
```